# Naming convention for pub(crate) constructor

Tags: rust, naming-conventions

I have a `struct` with two constructors, one for public usage (`pub fn new(...)`) and one for internal usage (`pub(crate) fn new_internal(...)`). NB: I use the term "internal" in analogy to C# `internal` keyword, I don't know what the equivalent Rust term is. The difference between the two methods is given by a check on a `&str` parameter to verify if its value is a reserved keyword. This check must only occur in the `pub(crate)` constructor. My question is just for stylistic purposes: is there any naming convention for internal functions to distinguish them from their public variant? In my specific case, how should I name the internal constructor?

Comment: Voted to close as opinion based, though if the second variant is unsafe, it's usually named `X_unchecked()` across the ecosystem.

Comment: Other versions I've seen in the wild are `do_X()` and `X_impl()`, though they're usually used for functions and not constructors.

Comment: `new_internal` doesn't tell you anything about the function that isn't obvious already from its not being `pub`. Call it something that describes why you have two functions in the first place. If `new` checks for a keyword, call the other one `new_unchecked` or `new_non_keyword`. Maybe `new_raw`. Don't use names to repeat stuff the code already says.

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK there are no such conventions.

Generally Rust, due to its strong type system, is among the languages that have lesser need for naming conventions related to types, scope, etc., compared to some other languages.